# UnboundLocalError causes

Tags: python

Does UnboundLocalError occur only when we try to use assignment operators (e.g. x += 5) on a non-local variable inside a function or there other cases? I tried using methods and functions (e.g. print) and it worked. I also tried to define a local variable (y) using a global variable (x) 
(y = x + 5) and it worked too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the presence of the assignment operator is what creates a new variable (of the same name) in the current scope. Calling mutating methods on the old object are not a problem, nor is doing something with that old value, since there's no question (if only a single assignment was ever used) which value you're talking about.

The concern here is not *the modification of a value*. The concern is *the ambiguity of the variable used*. This can also be solved using the `global` keyword, which specifically tells Python to use the global version, eliminating the ambiguity.

Remember also that Python variables (or `global`s) are sort of hoisted, like in JavaScript. Any variable used inside a specific scope is a variable in that scope *from the beginning of that scope*. That means a variable used inside a function is a variable in that scope from the start of the function, regardless of if it shows up half way through.

A really good reference for this is [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/05/15/understanding-unboundlocalerror-in-python). Some more specifics [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target).